# Prove that $\frac{n}{2}$ < 1 + $\frac{1}{2}$ + $\frac{1}{3}$ + ... + $\frac{1}{2^n-1}$ < n for every n $\in \Bbb{N}$, n > 1, by using induction.

Tags: induction

The basis checks out, and if we assume that the statement holds for n, we have to prove that it also holds for $n+1$:

$$\frac{n+1}{2} < 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{2^n-1} + \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^n+1} + ... + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1} < n+1$$

Now I've split the middle part into the sum of:
1 + $\frac{1}{2}$ + $\frac{1}{3}$ + ... + $\frac{1}{2^n-1}$ (which is defined in the assumption)
and
$\frac{1}{2^n}$ + $\frac{1}{2^n+1}$ + ... + $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1}$ .

But I don't know what to do from here on out.. If someone could show me a detailed answer i'd be really thankful, since this is my first time dealing with induction

Comment: Welcome to MSE!

You can use $\displaystyle \frac 1 2 =  \sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1} \frac 1 {2^{n+1}} < \sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1} \frac 1 k <  \sum_{k=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1} \frac 1 {2^n} = 1$ to solve this problem w/ induction. Can you continue from here?

Comment: @OM, for $n=1$ it is not defined. Otherwise the sequence you call $P(n)$ is actually $\sum_{r=1}^{2^n-1} \frac{1}{r}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Prove that $\frac{n}2<1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n-1}<n$ for all $n\in\mathbb {N}$, $n>1$

$P_r:=\sum_{a=1}^{2^r-1} \frac{1}{a}$

$P_{n}=1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^n-1}$

**Base Case:**

$n=2\\P_2=1+\frac{1}2+\frac{1}3\approx1.83$

Now, $\frac{2}2<P_2<2$ (True)

**Inductive Hypothesis:**

let assume, $\frac{m}2 \le P_{m} \le m$ is true where $m>1$ and $m\in \mathbb{N}$.

**Inductive Step:**

$$\therefore P_{m+1}{= 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^m-1} + \frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{2^m+1}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^{m+1}-1}\\   
= P_{m}+ \underbrace{\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{2^m+1}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^{m+1}-1}}_{2^m \text{terms}} \\
\geq \frac{m}{2} + 2^m\cdot\frac{1}{2^{m+1}} \quad (\, \because \frac{1}{2^{m+1}}<\text{ any one of $2^m$ terms })\\
=\frac{m+1}{2}}$$

Similarly,

$$P_{m+1}{= 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2^m-1} + \frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{2^m+1}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^{m+1}-1}\\   
= P_{m}+ \underbrace{\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{2^m+1}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^{m+1}-1}}_{2^m \text{terms}} \\
\leq m + 2^m\cdot\frac{1}{2^{m}}\quad (\, \because \frac{1}{2^{m}}\ge\text{ any one of $2^m$ terms })\\
=m+1}$$

$\therefore \frac{(m+1)}2 \le P_{m+1} \le (m+1)$

**Conclusion:**

$P_{m+1}$ is true when $P_m$ is true.

Thus, by the Principle of Mathematical Induction, the inequality
is valid for all
$n>1$ integers.

---

**Discussion:**

1. The most complex line in the proof is number of terms. We have a problem in
   that we have the terms from $\frac{1}
   {2^m}$ to $\frac{1}
   {2^{m+1}-1}$ to deal with, and we
   don’t know how many of them there are. Let’s look
   at the powers of $2$ as they increase:
   $${2^0 = 1\\
   2^1 = 2 = 1 + 1\\
   2^2 = 4 = 2 + 2\\
   2^3 = 8 = 4 + 4\\
   2^4 = 16 = 8 + 8\\
   2^5 = 32 = 16 + 16}$$
   The “distance” on the numberline from a power of $2$ to the next
   power is always the same as the previous power of $2$. That is,
   to get from $2^k$
   to $2^{k+1}$ we need $2^k$
   terms.
2. The minimum value among the terms $\frac{1}{2^m} + \frac{1}{2^m + 1} + \dots + \frac{1}{2^{m+1}-1}$ occurs at $\frac{1}{2^{m+1}-1}$, which is greater than $\frac{1}{2^{m+1}}$. If we substitute each of the $2^m$ terms with $\frac{1}{2^{m+1}}$, the resulting sum will always be smaller than the original. Similarly, the maximum value among the terms $\frac{1}{2^m} + \frac{1}{2^m + 1} + \dots + \frac{1}{2^{m+1}-1}$ occurs at $\frac{1}{2^m}$. If we substitute each of the $2^m$ terms with $\frac{1}{2^{m}}$, the resulting sum will always be greater than the original.

Comment: I don't understand why we multiply with $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ in the first part? Why is that element the least? How do we know that it's the least?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^n+1}+\dots+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1} \leq \frac{2^n}{2^{n}}$$ (Count the number of terms from $2^n$ to $2^{n+1}-1$ and
the greatest element among $\frac{1}{2^n}$,$\dots$, $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1}$).

Also

$$\frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}} < \frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}-1} \leq \frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^n+1}+\dots+ \frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1}$$
(Now the least element among $\frac{1}{2^n}$,$\dots$, $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1}$.

Comment: I understand the first sequence, however, how do we know that $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ is the least in the second? I would assume $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1}$ to be the least in the sequence since the denomenator keeps increasing, no? How does this happen?

Comment: Yes. You are right. Among the terms $ \frac{1}{2^n}, \frac{1}{2^n+1}, \dots, \frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1}$, the least is $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1}$. Hence the sum must be greater than or equal to $2^n$ copies of $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1}$. However, $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ is lesser than $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1}$. Hence $2^n$ copies of $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ must be lesser than the given sum. That was how $\frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}$ came into the picture.